# Given a random 2D shape/object, determine if it is possible to move this shape from A to B through the hall

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Given a random 2D shape, determine if it is possible to move this shape from A to B through the hall (see the image below).

How should I tackle this problem? I was wondering if it is possible to prove it for one certain shape and then use that proof to determine it for all other shapes, or is it impossible?

Note: the shapes/objects can be anything it could be an elephant or a giant spoon...
[image]

Comment: There's a related problem: to find the largest shape that can fit around that corner. This is currently unknown.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Are they any proofs available for certain cases? What are the known attempts made towards solving this problem? Are you referring to [Moving sofa problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem)?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem